# Efficient Parsing FIX Message c++

Tags: c++, performance, fix-protocol

I need to parse a file which contains the financial FIX protocol. A sample is below:

```
1128=99=24535=X49=CME75=2017040934=82452=2017040920070508394791460=201704092007050800000005799=10000000268=2279=0269=B48=900655=ESM783=23271=1473460731=100000005796=17263279=0269=C48=900655=ESM783=24271=2861528731=100000005796=1726310=219
```

My application will load many files each with many millions of rows of historical data so performance needs to be considered.

I have reviewed similar questions online around FIX parsing, as well as explored the QuickFix library (specifically using FIX::Message(string) to crack the message) but i aim to have a throughput better than what i was able to achieve using quickfix.

I wrote up a mock for the most common of the message types (Market Data Incremental Refresh) to see the kinds of speed i was achieving, and am most unimpressed with the result of ~60,000 messages / second including the file parsing of a 3m line file.

This is my first c++ application so i'm expecting there to be many flaws in my approach and any advice on how to improve its performance would be greatly appreciated.

Currently the flow is file->string->MDIncrementalRefresh. An MDIncrementalRefresh has two optional repeating groups which i'm using a vector to store as they are of unknown size from message to message.

I'm guessing the fact that i'm reconstructing MDIncrementalRefresh upon every update is causing unnecessary overhead compared to if i were to re-use the object by updating the contents of the previous MDIncrementalRefresh?

Thanks in Advance

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

std::vector<std::string> string_split(std::string s, const char delimiter)
{
    size_t start=0;
    size_t end=s.find_first_of(delimiter);

    std::vector<std::string> output;

    while (end <= std::string::npos)
    {
        output.emplace_back(s.substr(start, end-start));

        if (end == std::string::npos)
            break;

        start=end+1;
        end = s.find_first_of(delimiter, start);
    }

    return output;
}

const char FIX_FIELD_DELIMITER = '\x01';
const char FIX_KEY_DELIMITER = '=';

const int STR_TO_CHAR = 0;
const int KEY = 0;
const int VALUE = 1;

const string Field_TransactTime = "60";
const string Field_MatchEventIndicator = "5799";
const string Field_NoMDEntries = "268";
const string Field_MDUpdateAction = "279";
const string Field_MDEntryType = "269";
const string Field_SecurityID = "48";
const string Field_RptSeq = "83";
const string Field_MDEntryPx = "270";
const string Field_MDEntrySize = "271";
const string Field_NumberOfOrders = "346";
const string Field_MDPriceLevel = "1023";
const string Field_OpenCloseSettlFlag = "286";
const string Field_AggressorSide = "5797";
const string Field_TradingReferenceDate = "5796";
const string Field_HighLimitPrice = "1149";
const string Field_LowLimitPrice = "1148";
const string Field_MaxPriceVariation = "1143";
const string Field_ApplID = "1180";
const string Field_NoOrderIDEntries = "37705";
const string Field_OrderID = "37";
const string Field_LastQty = "32";
const string Field_SettlPriceType= "731";

class OrderIdEntry {
public:
    string OrderID;
    int LastQty;
};

struct MDEntry {
public:
    // necessary for defaults?
    char MDUpdateAction;
    char MDEntryType;
    int SecurityID;
    int RptSeq;
    double MDEntryPx;
    int MDEntrySize;
    int NumberOfOrders = 0;
    int MDPriceLevel = 0;
    int OpenCloseSettlFlag = 0;
    string SettlPriceType = "";
    int AggressorSide = 0;
    string TradingReferenceDate = "";
    double HighLimitPrice = 0.0;
    double LowLimitPrice = 0.0;
    double MaxPriceVariation = 0.0;
    int ApplID = 0;

};

class MDIncrementalRefresh {

public:
    string TransactTime;
    string MatchEventIndicator;
    int NoMDEntries;
    int NoOrderIDEntries = 0;
    vector<MDEntry> MDEntries;
    vector<OrderIdEntry> OrderIdEntries;

    MDIncrementalRefresh(const string& message)
    {

        MDEntry* currentMDEntry = nullptr;
        OrderIdEntry* currentOrderIDEntry = nullptr;

        for (auto fields : string_split(message, FIX_FIELD_DELIMITER))
        {
            vector<string> kv = string_split(fields, FIX_KEY_DELIMITER);

            // Header :: MDIncrementalRefresh

            if (kv[KEY] == Field_TransactTime) this->TransactTime = kv[VALUE];

            else if (kv[KEY] == Field_MatchEventIndicator) this->MatchEventIndicator = kv[VALUE];
            else if (kv[KEY] == Field_NoMDEntries) this->NoMDEntries = stoi(kv[VALUE]);
            else if (kv[KEY] == Field_NoOrderIDEntries) this->NoOrderIDEntries = stoi(kv[VALUE]);

            // Repeating Group :: MDEntry

            else if (kv[KEY] == Field_MDUpdateAction)
            {
                MDEntries.push_back(MDEntry());
                currentMDEntry = &MDEntries.back(); // use pointer for fast lookup on subsequent repeating group fields
                currentMDEntry->MDUpdateAction = kv[VALUE][STR_TO_CHAR];
            }
            else if (kv[KEY] == Field_MDEntryType) currentMDEntry->MDEntryType = kv[VALUE][STR_TO_CHAR];
            else if (kv[KEY] == Field_SecurityID) currentMDEntry->SecurityID = stoi(kv[VALUE]);
            else if (kv[KEY] == Field_RptSeq) currentMDEntry->RptSeq = stoi(kv[VALUE]);
            else if (kv[KEY] == Field_MDEntryPx) currentMDEntry->MDEntryPx = stod(kv[VALUE]);
            else if (kv[KEY] == Field_MDEntrySize) currentMDEntry->MDEntrySize = stoi(kv[VALUE]);
            else if (kv[KEY] == Field_NumberOfOrders) currentMDEntry->NumberOfOrders = stoi(kv[VALUE]);
            else if (kv[KEY] == Field_MDPriceLevel) currentMDEntry->MDPriceLevel = stoi(kv[VALUE]);
            else if (kv[KEY] == Field_OpenCloseSettlFlag) currentMDEntry->OpenCloseSettlFlag = stoi(kv[VALUE]);
            else if (kv[KEY] == Field_SettlPriceType) currentMDEntry->SettlPriceType= kv[VALUE];
            else if (kv[KEY] == Field_AggressorSide) currentMDEntry->AggressorSide = stoi(kv[VALUE]);
            else if (kv[KEY] == Field_TradingReferenceDate) currentMDEntry->TradingReferenceDate = kv[VALUE];
            else if (kv[KEY] == Field_HighLimitPrice) currentMDEntry->HighLimitPrice = stod(kv[VALUE]);
            else if (kv[KEY] == Field_LowLimitPrice) currentMDEntry->LowLimitPrice = stod(kv[VALUE]);
            else if (kv[KEY] == Field_MaxPriceVariation) currentMDEntry->MaxPriceVariation = stod(kv[VALUE]);
            else if (kv[KEY] == Field_ApplID) currentMDEntry->ApplID = stoi(kv[VALUE]);

            // Repeating Group :: OrderIDEntry
            else if (kv[KEY] == Field_OrderID) {
                OrderIdEntries.push_back(OrderIdEntry());
                currentOrderIDEntry = &OrderIdEntries.back();
                currentOrderIDEntry->OrderID = kv[VALUE];
            }

            else if (kv[KEY] == Field_LastQty) currentOrderIDEntry->LastQty = stol(kv[VALUE]);
        }
    }


};

int main() {

    //std::string filename = "test/sample";

    std::string line;
    std::ifstream file (filename);

    int count = 0;
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        while ( std::getline( file, line ) )
        {
            MDIncrementalRefresh md(line);
            if (md.TransactTime != "") {
                count++;
            }
        }
        file.close();
    }
    cout << count << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `This is my first c++ application` And you are insisting on throughput from the start. Get a code which does your job rather than harping on efficiency. And without a profiler you would be so wrong in optimizing.

Comment: @DumbCoder i appreciate your taking the time to review my question. Whilst i mentioned it was my first c++ application i did not say it was my first time writing software. As such i am perfectly capable of getting a solution working but was hoping for some helpful guidance on how to best profile and understand potential bottlenecks (such as the fact that the repeated call to split_string could implicitly be expanding heap allocations).

Answer (score 2):

For those who are interested, majority of the time being spent processing the code above was in the split_string function. The large number of calls to split_string resulted in many (expensive) allocations being done on the heap.

An alternative implementation split_string_optim re-uses a pre-allocated vector. This prevents unnecessary heap allocation/expansion upon every split_string function call. The below sample running 1.5m iterations suggests a 3.4x speed improvement. By utilising vector.clear() which itself does not free allocated memory back to the heap, it ensures subsequent split_string calls to split_string_optim where the resulting vector size <= previous have no additional allocations.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void string_split_optim(std::vector<std::string>& output, const std::string &s, const char delimiter)
{
    output.clear();

    size_t start = 0;
    size_t end = s.find_first_of(delimiter);


    while (end <= std::string::npos)
    {
        output.emplace_back(s.substr(start, end - start));

        if (end == std::string::npos)
            break;

        start = end + 1;
        end = s.find_first_of(delimiter, start);
    }

}


int main()
{
    const int NUM_RUNS = 1500000;
    const std::string s = "1128=9\u00019=174\u000135=X\u000149=CME\u000175=20170403\u000134=1061\u000152=20170402211926965794928\u000160=20170402211926965423233\u00015799=10000100\u0001268=1\u0001279=1\u0001269=1\u000148=9006\u000155=ESM7\u000183=118\u0001270=236025.0\u0001271=95\u0001346=6\u00011023=9\u000110=088\u0001";

    std::vector<std::string> vec;

    // standard
    clock_t tStart = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RUNS; ++i)
    {
        vec = string_split(s, '=');
    }

    printf("Time taken: %.2fs\n", (double) (clock() - tStart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    // reused vector
    tStart = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RUNS; ++i)
    {
        string_split_optim(vec, s, '=');
        vec.clear();
    }

    printf("Time taken: %.2fs\n", (double) (clock() - tStart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

The result on my macbook was a 3.4x improvement.

```
Time taken: 6.60s
Time taken: 1.94s
```

Additionally, the MDIncrementalRefresh object was being repetitively constructed (on the stack, but it's vector members were also being expanded on the heap). In line with the above findings on split_string, i decided to re-use the temporary object and simply clear its previous state, resulting in another significant performance increase.